# Questions regarding decomposition of density function

Tags: probability

Is this formula true:

$f_{123}=f_{12} f_{23} f_{13 \mid 2}$ 
where $f$ means suitable probability density function?

Comment: This notation isn't standard or isn't clear from the minimal context given; please explain what the symbols mean. Are you talking about the marginal probability densities of a three-dimensional random vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's true in general then it's true in the simplest nontrivial discrete case.  Suppose $\Pr( (X_1,X_2,X_3)\in \{0,1\}^3) = 1,$ i.e. each of the three random variabales is either $0$ or $1$.

I will take $f_{12}$ to mean the marginal density of $(X_1,X_2)$ (which in this case is a probability mass function), and similarly $f_{23}$.

Let $E_1,E_2,E_3$ respectively be the events $X_1=1,X_2=1,X_3=1.$

Then ask whether $$\Pr(E_1\cap E_2)\cdot\Pr(E_2\cap E_3) \cdot \Pr(E_1 \cap E_3\mid E_2) = \Pr(E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3). \tag 1$$  The very simplest nontrivial distribution to apply this to is the one in which $E_1,D_2,E_3$ are independent and each has probability $1/2$. In that case, $(1)$ says $1/64 = 1/8.$